# Error when trying to launch an application using GTK and glade

Tags: gtk, glade

When we try to launch an application that uses GTK libraries of version GTK 2.0 we get the below error:

> Message: Unhandled tag: 'requires'

`'requires'` appears only once in the faulty XML file. Glade version used is `3.6.1`.

Could you please help us with the query? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Glade XML file may contain the GTK minimum version number required. Check you're using at least that version.

Comment: Glade XML contains this line:requires lib="gtk+" version="2.16".GTK version used in GTK+ 2.0 . However teh same XML works fine in another server that has the same version(2.0) of GTK installed.

Comment: GTK 2.0 is 11 years old, I can't believe you're using this on a server. You're mixing the major version here with the full version number. For example, on my machine with GTK development packages installed, `pkg-config --modversion gtk+-2.0` returns `2.24.10`. The package name for GTK 2.x on my machine is `lib64gtk+2.0_0-2.24.10-4.mga2`. Yeah, the name starts with 2.0, but you should think of it like `2.x`. Check again the version your machines are using.

Comment: Thanks for the information.The version installed is 2.4.9.So is version the cause of the error?I tried commenting the requires tag in the xml.But it resulted in many more errors.

Comment: Commenting the `requires` tag won't help. The UI was designed for GTK >= 2.16, so it most likely uses widgets or signal that didn't exist before that version. The "many more errors" you get come from these features that GTK 2.4 can't possibly know about, as it was released 3 years before GTK 2.16.